# jaxws client get https wsdl errors

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws

I am testing a web service hosted on `https`. I use `jaxws` for the connection.
This retrieves the wsdl first but that's where the error occurs. I saved the certificate in IE on my local machine and created a keystore from it, as described in [JAX-WS-https-client](http://www.coderanch.com/t/224356/Web-Services/java/JAX-WS-https-client) and changed JVM arguments so that the keystore loads.
This did achieve that the url used to retrieve the wsdl contained protocol https instead of http, so things started to look better. But now I get the following error:

`SystemException: PropagatedException: WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Unable to resolve imported document at 'https://www.eway.com.au/gateway/rebill/test/manageRebill_test.asmx?wsdl'.: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Does this mean that the certificate was copied to filesystem incorrectly?
Is something else wrong? What to do?

I should note that when exporting a certificate from IE, the option is given to export the private key or not. When **not** exporting the private key, then it can be saved as `.cer` file which is necessary for creating the keystore. On the other hand, when I try to export the private key, the file extension is `.pfx` and this cannot be converted to a keystore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad - I had Fiddler running and thus used a certificate issued by Fiddler.
When I added the real certificate to the keystore, the webservice call was OK.